# How do I get my building back?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built a costume shop in Minecraft, but when I look at it next, it's disappeared!

I built it a couple of weeks ago and have had no trouble with it loading, then this morning it was no longer there. I put a lot of time into that building, and I have restarted Minecraft, but don't know what else to try. Also, in my library, the librarian I had encased in fences escaped.

I used Glowstone For The building, I used Cobble Stairs For The Register, And I used Armour Stands For About, Everything else. (except the costumes) kinda like SethBling, puts armour stands in EVERYTHING.

I really don't want to lose my costume shop. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Try using 1.8 if your shop doesn't use 1.9 stuff

Comment: Well, what did you do???

Comment: It could of been saved previously. Might be on the disk still.

Answer (score 4):

1.9 has a serious infestation of bugs. On several occasions I have seen chunks either reset to their generated state or have a completely new layout. I tried quitting and loading the world and or game a couple of times and sometimes my buildings and such would return.

I recommend copying your save file to back it up.

Answer (score 1):

If you upgraded to version 1.9, it may have been deleted as a bug from the snapshots.  Otherwise if you made a previous save you can reload from the save. If this is a big problem and none of the above work. If you reload your game to a working version that you built it in try like 1.8.8. You could do a google search on this problem and most likely it is just a chunk glitch.

Next time, when you build something big and that you spent a lot of time in. Take the time to copy the world save.

Windows

1. Open start
2. Type run
3. Press enter
4. In the field type '%appdata%'
5. Open folder '.minecraft'
6. Open folder 'saves'
7. Find the folder that says your world name
8. Copy the folder to your desired location(that is your safe copy)

Mac or Linux

http://www.howtogeek.com/207484/how-to-find-your-minecraft-saved-games-folder/

I hope this will help you